# Django,HTML:Display the loader after submitting the post request

Tags: html, django, post, loader

In my application after pressing the submit button the POST request will be sent to server.I want to display the loader until the server responds.
Here is my HTML template:

```
{%load static %}
{% load staticfiles %} 
<html>
   <style>
      form {
      }
      input[type=text], input[type=password] {
      width: 30%;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      margin: 12px 0;
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      button {
      background-color: #35a5f0;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 20px;
      margin: 6px 0;
      border: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 30%;
      }
      button:hover {
      opacity: 0.8;
      }
      .cancelbtn {
      width: auto;
      padding: 10px 18px;
      background-color: #f44336;
      }
      .container {
      padding: 16px;
      }
      span.psw {
      float: right;
      padding-top: 16px;
      }
      /* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
      @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      span.psw {
      display: block;
      float: none;
      }
      .cancelbtn {
      width: 100%;
      }
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
         <img src = "{% static 'logo.png' %}" width="150" height="100">
         <img src = "{% static 'Timesheets.png' %}" width="150" height="100">
      </div>
      <form action="/new_user/" method="post">
         <div class="container">
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
               <input type="text" placeholder="Enter valid Email ID" name="email_id" required>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
               <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
            <p> {{status}}</p>
         </div>
         <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
            <span class="psw"> <a href="/login_page/">Login Page</a></span>
         </div>
         <div style="display: flex; justify-content:center;">
            <span class="psw"> <a href="/forgot_passwd/">Forgot password? </a></span>
         </div>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is my view.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from send_email import send_email
from delete_all_user import delete_all_user
import os, random, string

@csrf_exempt

def index(request):
        if request.POST:
                email_id = request.POST['email_id']
                print email_id
                user_name = str(email_id.split("@")[0])
                if '.' in user_name:
                                print "Dot present"
                                user_name = user_name.replace('.','_')
                print user_name

                if not (User.objects.filter(username = user_name).exists()):
                        user = User.objects.create_user(user_name)
                        user_password = get_random_password()
                        user.set_password(user_password)
                        user.email = request.POST['email_id']
                        user.save()
                        print "User not exists"
                        print dir(user)
                        if send_email("Use bleow credentials to login:"+"<br>"+"<br>"+"Username: "+request.POST['email_id']+"<br>"+"Password: "+user_password+"<br>",request.POST['email_id']):
                                        return render(request, 'new_user.html', {"status":"Not a valid CommScope email address"})
                        return render(request, 'new_user.html', {"status":"Email has been sent on "+request.POST['email_id'] + ".Please check your inbox"})
                else:
                        return render(request, 'new_user.html', {"status":"User already exists..."})
        else:
                return render(request, 'new_user.html', {})

def get_random_password():
        length = 13
        chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
        random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))
        return(''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(length)))
```

I want to add loader after submit button is pressed and before status string is being received.
How to do that?Is it possible only with the HTML?Please help.

Comment: If you ajax post , it will be good for you to load the loader until you will get the result.

Comment: How to do ajax post?Can't it possible with html form?

Comment: Yes, I will answer it.